# What is critical resources to a std::mutex object

Tags: c++

I am new to concurrency and I am having doubts in `std::mutex`. Say I've a int a; and books are telling me to declare a mutex amut; to get exclusive access over a. Now my question is how a mutex object is recognizing which critical resources it has to protect ? I mean which variable?
say I've two variables int a,b; now i declare mutex abmut;  Now abmut will protect what???
both a and b or only a or b???

Comment: Keep reading until you get to the part about `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: I know that look guard... But a mutex object will protect what???

Comment: I mean lock guard gets a lock on what???

Comment: Please stop the triple question marks, it's really annoying to read. Next to that, a mutex for just protecting int is cumbersome, you might want to consider [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

Comment: A mutex does not protect objects. It protects sections of code from simultaneous execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::mutex` does not protect any data at all. A mutex works like this:

- When you try to lock a mutex you look if the mutex is not already locked, else you wait until it is unlocked.
- When you're finished using a mutex you unlock it, else threads that are waiting will do that forever.

How does that protect things? consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

struct example {
    static int shared_variable;
    static void incr_shared() 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            shared_variable++; 
        }
    }
};
int example::shared_variable = 0;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::future<void> > handles;
    handles.reserve(10000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        handles.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, example::incr_shared));
    }
    for(auto& handle: handles) handle.wait();
    std::cout << example::shared_variable << std::endl;
}
```

You might expect it to print 1000000000, but you don't really have a guarantee of that. We should include a mutex, like this:

```
struct example {
    static int shared_variable;
    static std::mutex guard;
    static void incr_shared() 
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{ guard };
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            shared_variable++; 
        }
    }
};
```

So what does this exactly do? First of all `std::lock_guard` uses [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) to call `mutex.lock()` when it's created and `mutex.unlock` when it's destroyed, this last one happens when it leaves scope (here when the function exits). So in this case only one thread can be executing the for loop because as soon as a thread passes the `lock_guard` it holds the lock, and we saw before that no other thread can hold it. Therefore this loop is now safe. Note that we could also put the `lock_guard` inside the loop, but that might make your program slow (locking and unlocking is relatively expensive).

So in conclusion, a `mutex` protects blocks of code, in our example the for-loop, not the variable itself. If you want variable protection, consider taking a look at [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). The following example is for example again unsafe because `decr_shared` can be called simultaneously from any thread.

```
struct example {
    static int shared_variable;
    static std::mutex guard;

    static void decr_shared() { shared_variable--; }
    static void incr_shared() 
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{ guard };
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            shared_variable++; 
        }
    }
};
```

This however is again safe, because now the variable itself is protected, in any code that uses it.

```
struct example {
    static std::atomic_int shared_variable;

    static void decr_shared() { shared_variable--; }
    static void incr_shared() 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            shared_variable++; 
        }
    }
};
std::atomic_int example::shared_variable{0};
```

Answer (score 7):

Your doubts are justified: it doesn't. That's your job as a programmer, to make sure you only access `a` if you've got the mutex. If somebody else got the mutex, do not access `a` or you will have the same problems you'd have without the mutex. That goes for all thread-syncronization constructs. *You* can *use* them to protect a resource. They don't do it on their own.

Comment: You mean to say that if i create a mutex in a function all access to all variables will be exclusive

Comment: If you aquired a lock on a mutex, you can be sure that no other thread has a lock on it and no other thread will get a lock on it until you unlock it. The code between a lock and an unlock is safe so you can access any resource there without interference from code that is also guarded by a lock/unlock of the same mutex. If you access the resource without a mutex.lock, you are still in trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Mutex is more like a sign rather than a lock. When someone sees a sign saying "occupied" in a public washroom, he will wait until the user gets out and flips the sign. But you have to teach him to wait when seeing the sign. The sign itself won't prevent him from breaking in. Of course, the "wait" order is already set by mutex.lock(), so you can use it conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

mutex is used to synchronize access to a resource. Say you have a data say int, where you are going to do read write operation using an getter and a setter. So both getter and setters will use the same mutex to to sync read/write operation.

both of these function will lock the mutex at the beginning and unlock it before it returns. you can use scoped_lock that will automatically unlock on its destructor.

```
void setter(value_type v){
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
  value = v;
}    
value_type getter() const{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mutex doesn't inherently protect any specific variables... instead, the programmer needs to realise that they have some group of 1 or more variables that several threads may attempt to use, then use a mutex so that only one of those threads can be running such variable-using/changing code at any point in time.

Note especially that you're only protected from other threads' code accessing/modifying those variables if their code locks the same mutex during the variable access.  A mutex used by only one thread protects nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you sit at a table with your friends and a delicious cake (the resources you want to guard, e.g. some integer a) in the middle. In addition you have a single tennis ball (this is our mutex). Now, only a single person can have the ball (lock the mutex using a lock_guard or similar mechanisms), but everyone can eat the cake (access the integer a).

As a group you can decide to set up a rule that only whoever has the ball may eat from the cake (only the person who has locked the mutex may access a). This person may relinquish the ball by putting it on the table (unlock the mutex), so another person can grab it (lock the mutex). This way you ensure that no one stabs another person with the fork, while frantically eating the cake.

Setting up and upholding a rule like described in the last paragraph is your job as a programmer. There is no inherent connection between a mutex and some resource (e.g. some integer a).